# Finding SQL Service account in active Directory with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Using Powershell I need to find check if the "NT Service\MSSQL$nameofServer" has the propery trustfordelegatin set to true at the domain Controller.

If this was a user account I would just do this:

```
get-ADuser userdummy -Properties trustedfordelegation|select trustedfordelegation
```

For a user this works perfectly. I need to do the equivalent for the sql service account to see if the property is set to true.

Comment: NT Service would be a local account, so I think you'll need get-localuser, but there doesn't appear to be an equivalent property.  See properties with  `get-localuser -name 'NT Service' | select *`  or  `get-localuser |?{$_.name -like 'NT Serv*'}| select-object -Property *`

Comment: I am not getting any results. Also linked server transactions are failing because the service account on the server does not have this setting to true.  But I need to be able to query its value so I can prove my case.

Comment: This may help... https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a736f3a4-a477-4cbf-91e2-8237d0e7a4cb/sql-server-not-show-as-a-service-for-delegation?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: Or [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/06/24/how-to-find-service-account-for-sql-server-and-sql-server-agent-interview-question-of-the-week-179/)